# Hide Web Page From Public - WebMatrix 3

Tags: c#, razor, webmatrix

I am using C# Razor in order to make a social network. There are wepages that contain sensible data and I don't want someone to go to that url and see it. Not even by going to the **Inspect Element** and open it through there. So is there a way to warn the user that "This web page is not allowed"?

Comment: Is there a name for your social network, so I can stay the hell away from it?

Comment: If your goal is to create a social network, WebMatrix is the absolutely wrong tool to be using. Get Visual Studio and create a real web application.

Comment: yea, I mean, I'm new to programing so I started from the bottom but I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Louis, you should get this book here which helped me a ton. http://www.apress.com/9781430257523

The literal answer you are looking for concerns the use of authorization attributes you place above controller actions or controllers themselves. So an action might look like this

```
[Authorize]    
public ActionResult UserAccount(Guid id){...}
```

By setting up authentication using [ASP.Net Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity) you will be able to automatically redirect visitors who are not logged in to another page etc.

Also if you need to make sure that the current logged in user is not going to (for example) another user's personal page (account settings?) you would do a simple check on the server side to prevent this. Something like so (Pseudo code)

```
if(User.Identity.GetUserId() != account.OwningUserId)
   return RedirectToAction("404", "Shared");
```

Comment: This is very useful thank you very much! sory if the question es silly but I am new to progaming so I am starting from the bottom

Comment: No problem! If you think I answered your question mark my answer as the correct one! Have fun learning MVC.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement authentication and authorization in order to control who can actually access any given route in an mvc application. I can only recommend that you start by reading the official site www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security about authorization and authentication.

With the proper authentication/authorization the server will simply not send any data, or you could redirect to a specific "not allowed page"